# Oracle SQL LAG Function

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, window-functions

I'd appreciate some help with this code, I'm getting a 'missing keyword' error. I've never used the Lag function before, so hopefully I using it correctly. Thanks for your help. Gav

```
CREATE VIEW GS_Date AS
SELECT                        
        DATE_DATE, 
        DATE_FLAG,
        CASE WHEN  LAG ( DATE_FLAG)  OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE ) = '1' THEN DATE_STEP = ( LAG ( DATE_FLAG)  OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE ) ) + '1'
                 WHEN  LAG ( DATE_FLAG)  OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE ) = '0' AND LAG ( DATE_FLAG)  OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE ) =  '-1'  THEN DATE_STEP = ( LAG ( DATE_FLAG)  OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE ) ) + '1'
                 ELSE DATE_STEP = LAG ( DATE_FLAG)  OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE )  END AS DATE_STEP
FROM DATE_GROUP
```

Comment: You can't assign variables or columns using `DATE_STEP = ...`  in a SQL statement. Unrelated to the error: `lag()` returns a number, don't compare it to a string. `'1'` is a string constant. `1` is a number.

Comment: To find the error, temporarily skip the case, and try one LAG at the time.

Comment: Thank you for your help, working now.

Comment: @jarlh - except that, in this example, the mistake has to do with how CASE is used; LAG is perfectly fine!

Comment: @Gavin - if it is "working now", that means you figured out that you were using CASE incorrectly. It should be `CASE when... then... (just the value), etc  as DATE_STEP`

Comment: @mathguy, yes, I didn't even read more than case something. Some people are just too lazy, writing very long and complex queries without even trying its parts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the CASE expression; you were using LAG correctly.

Other points: Don't add strings like `'1'` and `'-1'` to numbers. Add numbers - you don't need the single quotes.

Also, if in a computation something is common and only the "last part" is different, you can use the CASE expression "at the end". Like below:

**Note**: On re-reading the original post, the formula needs to be more complicated (I didn't get it exactly right). Not changing the answer, since it still illustrates the same ideas I meant to share. BUT: Looking at the original post, there is a condition "`when LAG = 0 and LAG = -1`" - that can never be true. What was meant is probably "OR" instead of "AND". In the formula I wrote below, this means one more `WHEN...THEN...` branch.

```
LAG(DATE_FLAG) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) 
       + CASE LAG(DATE_FLAG) OVER (ORDER BY DATE ) WHEN 1 THEN  1
                                                   WHEN 0 THEN -1
                                                   ELSE         0  END AS DATE_STEP
```

**Further edit**: Looking at it again, it seems when the flag is 1, 0 or -1 then we must add 1, otherwise add 0... then it's easier to use a "simple CASE expression" instead of a "searched CASE expression" as I did. Something like:

```
LAG(...) ...
   + CASE WHEN LAG(...) ... IN (-1, 0, 1) THEN 1
          ELSE                                 0 END AS DATE_STEP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
CREATE VIEW GS_Date AS
SELECT DATE_DATE,
       DATE_FLAG,
       CASE
         WHEN LAG(DATE_FLAG) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_DATE) = '1' THEN
          (LAG(DATE_FLAG) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_DATE)) + '1'
         WHEN LAG(DATE_FLAG) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_DATE) = '0'   AND LAG(DATE_FLAG)  OVER(ORDER BY DATE_DATE) = '-1' THEN
          (LAG(DATE_FLAG) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_DATE)) + '1'
         ELSE
          LAG(DATE_FLAG) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_DATE)
       END AS DATE_STEP
  FROM DATE_GROUP
```

Comment: Don't add strings like `'1'` to numbers! If the OP did so, and you are trying to help them, that's not difficult to recognize and point out, even if it wasn't the reason for the error they encountered.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't have to keep writing `LAG( ... ) OVER ( ... )` statements, get the `LAG` value in a sub-query and then use `CASE` or `DECODE` in the outer query:

```
CREATE VIEW GS_Date AS
SELECT  DATE_DATE,
        DATE_FLAG,
        DECODE(
          DATE_STEP,
          1, 2,
          0, 1,
          -1, 0,
          DATE_STEP
        ) AS DATE_STEP
FROM    (
  SELECT  DATE_DATE, 
          DATE_FLAG,
          LAG ( DATE_FLAG )  OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE ) AS DATE_STEP
  FROM    DATE_GROUP
)'
```

Also, your second `WHEN` clause will never be true:

```
WHEN LAG ( DATE_FLAG ) OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE ) = '0'
AND  LAG ( DATE_FLAG ) OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_DATE ) = '-1'
THEN ...
```

Since the value can never be both `-1` and `0`. I've assumed you meant to use `OR` rather than `AND`.